# Strange TypeScript definitely typed code resolution in WebStorm

Tags: node.js, typescript, webstorm

I'm using WebStorm 2016.1.2 and TypeScript 2 (set custom version in WebStorm's settings).

I've installed `@types/node`, `@types/express`, `@types/serve-static` packages (since I do not need 'typings' any more for TypeScript 2)

Root folder contains following `tsconfig`:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  }
}
```

`server` subfolder contains this `tsconfig`:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitHelpers": false,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
}
```

server/serverApp.ts:

```
/// <reference types="express" />
/// <reference types="express-serve-static-core" />
/// <reference types="serve-static" />
/// <reference types="node" />

import * as express from 'express'
var path = require('path');

export class ServerApp {

    private _App: express.Application; //express.Express

    constructor() {
        this._App = express();
    }

    public setRoutes() {
        this._App.use(express.static(path.resolve("./"), { index: 'index.html' }));
...
```

Root folder compilation works OK (Angular2); `server` folder compilation works too.

But when I <kbd>Ctrl + Click</kbd> on "express" word in `import * as express from 'express'` string - IDE navigates me to `express` node_modules folder, not to `@types/express` folder.

Clicking to "Application" in `express.Application` - gives me nothing.

And I have no Intellisense for `this._App.use`, `express().use`, `express.static` etc.

So it looks like all objects resolved as ANY and IDE doesn't have enough information at design time.

How can I get working Intellisense for express etc.?

Comment: You should remove the `//// <reference`s. Type definitions will be 'automatically' loaded from the node_modules/@types folder

Comment: WS 2016.1.2 doesn't support the "@types" feature. Please try WS 2016.2 or (better) 2016.3

Comment: Thanks man, works with 2016.3 with bundled TS!